Getting SSLHandshakeException With Apache Nifi ConsumeJMS using JNDI Configurations
Hi We are configuring ConsumeJMS Processor using JNDI Controller service and ConsumeJMS Properties.
as Shown here.


and the controller service configurations are as follow.

This works perfectly in test pod, but when we deploy same changes in other server different environment pod we get following error.
o.apache.nifi.jms.processors.ConsumeJMS ConsumeJMS[id=xxxxxxxxxxxx] Failed to initialize JMS Connection Factory: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
↳ causes: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
↳ causes: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
↳ causes: javax.naming.CommunicationException: WFNAM00018: Failed to connect to remote host [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target]
↳ causes: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Could not obtain JMS Connection Factory from JNDI"}
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Could not obtain JMS Connection Factory from JNDI
    at org.apache.nifi.jms.cf.JndiJmsConnectionFactoryHandler.lookupConnectionFactory(JndiJmsConnectionFactoryHandler.java:154)
    at org.apache.nifi.jms.cf.JndiJmsConnectionFactoryHandler.getConnectionFactory(JndiJmsConnectionFactoryHandler.java:78)
    at org.apache.nifi.jms.cf.JndiJmsConnectionFactoryProvider.getConnectionFactory(JndiJmsConnectionFactoryProvider.java:68)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor170.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:254)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:105)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy176.getConnectionFactory(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.nifi.jms.processors.AbstractJMSProcessor.buildTargetResource(AbstractJMSProcessor.java:284)
    at org.apache.nifi.jms.processors.AbstractJMSProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractJMSProcessor.java:184)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1202)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:214)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:103)
    at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: WFNAM00018: Failed to connect to remote host
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteNamingProvider.getPeerIdentityForNaming(RemoteNamingProvider.java:110)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteNamingProvider.getPeerIdentityForNaming(RemoteNamingProvider.java:53)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.NamingProvider.getPeerIdentityForNamingUsingRetry(NamingProvider.java:103)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteNamingProvider.getPeerIdentityForNamingUsingRetry(RemoteNamingProvider.java:91)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteContext.lambda$lookupNative$0(RemoteContext.java:189)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.NamingProvider.performExceptionAction(NamingProvider.java:220)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteContext.performWithRetry(RemoteContext.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteContext.lookupNative(RemoteContext.java:188)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.AbstractFederatingContext.lookup(AbstractFederatingContext.java:74)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.AbstractFederatingContext.lookup(AbstractFederatingContext.java:60)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyRootContext.lookup(WildFlyRootContext.java:144)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
    at org.apache.nifi.jms.cf.JndiJmsConnectionFactoryHandler.lookupConnectionFactory(JndiJmsConnectionFactoryHandler.java:100)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:353)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:296)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:291)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1074)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1061)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1008)
    at org.xnio.ssl.JsseSslConduitEngine.handleHandshake(JsseSslConduitEngine.java:549)
    at org.xnio.ssl.JsseSslConduitEngine.wrap(JsseSslConduitEngine.java:244)
    at org.xnio.ssl.JsseSslStreamSinkConduit.write(JsseSslStreamSinkConduit.java:113)
    at org.xnio.ssl.JsseSslStreamSinkConduit.write(JsseSslStreamSinkConduit.java:77)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.write(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:154)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnection$RemoteWriteListener.handleEvent(RemoteConnection.java:264)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnection$RemoteWriteListener.handleEvent(RemoteConnection.java:243)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.conduits.WriteReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.writeReady(WriteReadyHandler.java:65)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:94)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:591)
    at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:599)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:565)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.ConnectionInfo$None.getConnection(ConnectionInfo.java:82)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.ConnectionInfo.getConnection(ConnectionInfo.java:55)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doGetConnection(EndpointImpl.java:499)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.getConnectedIdentity(EndpointImpl.java:445)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.UncloseableEndpoint.getConnectedIdentity(UncloseableEndpoint.java:52)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteNamingProvider.getFuturePeerIdentityPrivileged(RemoteNamingProvider.java:151)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteNamingProvider.lambda$getFuturePeerIdentity$0(RemoteNamingProvider.java:138)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteNamingProvider.getFuturePeerIdentity(RemoteNamingProvider.java:138)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteNamingProvider.getPeerIdentity(RemoteNamingProvider.java:126)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteNamingProvider.getPeerIdentityForNaming(RemoteNamingProvider.java:106)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:276)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:632)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1074)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1061)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1008)
    at org.xnio.ssl.JsseSslConduitEngine.handleHandshake(JsseSslConduitEngine.java:549)
    at org.xnio.ssl.JsseSslConduitEngine.wrap(JsseSslConduitEngine.java:244)
    at org.xnio.ssl.JsseSslStreamSinkConduit.write(JsseSslStreamSinkConduit.java:113)
    at org.xnio.ssl.JsseSslStreamSinkConduit.write(JsseSslStreamSinkConduit.java:77)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.write(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:154)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnection$RemoteWriteListener.handleEvent(RemoteConnection.java:264)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnection$RemoteWriteListener.handleEvent(RemoteConnection.java:243)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.conduits.WriteReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.writeReady(WriteReadyHandler.java:65)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:94)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:591)
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 25 common frames omitted


I had try using setting the env while building the InitialContext in Nifi code as follow.
private Context createInitialContext() throws NamingException {
        final Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, context.getProperty(JNDI_INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY).evaluateAttributeExpressions().getValue().trim());
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, context.getProperty(JNDI_PROVIDER_URL).evaluateAttributeExpressions().getValue().trim());

        final String principal = context.getProperty(JNDI_PRINCIPAL).evaluateAttributeExpressions().getValue();
        if (principal != null) {
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, principal);
        }

        final String credentials = context.getProperty(JNDI_CREDENTIALS).getValue();
        if (credentials != null) {
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, credentials);
        }

        propertyDescriptors.forEach(descriptor -> {
            if (descriptor.isDynamic()) {
                env.put(descriptor.getName(), context.getProperty(descriptor).evaluateAttributeExpressions().getValue());
            }
        });
        
        final String enableSSL = context.getProperty(JndiJmsConnectionFactoryProperties.ENABLE_SSL).evaluateAttributeExpressions().getValue();
        logger.info("enableSSL: "+enableSSL);
        if (!enableSSL.equals("true")) {
            env.put("java.naming.security.authentification", "none");
            env.put("jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_STARTTLS", "false");
            env.put("jboss.naming.client.remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED", "false");
            env.put("jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "false");
        }
        
        final Context initialContext = new InitialContext(env);
        return initialContext;
    }

But it didn't work
Edit 1:
I tried a fix and it works but not as expected.

This updates the default global SSL Context,
I want similar logic which should be specific to this consume jms processor and should not affect the global SSL Context.
        try {
            String jndiTruststorePath =  context.getProperty(JNDI_TRUSTSTORE).evaluateAttributeExpressions().getValue().trim();
            // Load the truststore
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            FileInputStream file = null;
            try {
                file = new FileInputStream(jndiTruststorePath);
                trustStore.load(file, "changeit".toCharArray());
            } finally {
                if (file != null) {
                    file.close();
                }
            }

            // Initialize TrustManager
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

            // Set up SSLContext
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
            
            // Set the default SSL context
            SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);

            logger.info("Successfully configured the default SSL context");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed to configure SSL context", e);
            throw new ProcessException(e);
        }
        


Are you connecting to a standalone instance of ActiveMQ Artemis or an instance of ActiveMQ Artemis embedded in WildFly?

@JustinBertram we are connecting to an instance of ActiveMQ Artemis embedded in WildFly.
We do a jndi lookup for ConnectionFactory Object, using which we connect to Broker.
But this error seems to be with initial jndi lookup, we cannot import certificates in nifi global truststore, we want a workaround to set the jvm ssl properties to point to a specific truststore everytime we run this processor and then perform a lookup.

I had tried building a context but it will affect the global nifi ssl context which is not expected it should be applicable only for consume jms processor
